# I am unable to access properties set in my Proxy service from the fault sequence in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have set some functions in my proxy service but whenever I try to access those in the fault sequence it returns null.
I am trying to set a logger in my service I need the details of the proxies and need to send the error to a queue from which I will have to send it to a Cloud server.

Below is my Proxy and my Fault sequence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="TestFaultSeq"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target faultSequence="conf:/resources/sequences/ProxyFaultSequence.xml">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
         <sequence key="conf:/resources/sequences/InitializeFaultLogger.xml"/>
         <log separator=", inside TestFAult">
            <property name="From" expression="get-property('From')"/>
         </log>
         <property name="propFAult"
                   expression="//Request/yoyol"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2015_1">
                  <timeout>
                     <duration>30000</duration>
                     <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                  </timeout>
                  <suspendOnFailure>
                     <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
                     <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                  </suspendOnFailure>
               </address>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log separator=", inside out**"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="InitializeFaultLogger">
    <property name="ServiceName" expression="fn:concat('SN:',get-property('To'))" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="IncomingRequest" expression="$body/" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="TransactionId" expression="//*[local-name()='transactionId']/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="Caller" expression="get-property('From')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log level="full" separator=",**inside initialize fault***" description="">
        <property name="ServiceNAme" expression="get-property('ServiceName')"/>
        <property name="TransactionIdW" expression="get-property('TransactionId')"/>
        <property name="CallerW" expression="get-property('From')"/>
        <property name="IncomingRequestW" expression="get-property('IncomingRequest')"/>
    </log>
</sequence>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ProxyFaultSequence">
    <log level="full" separator=", **inside Fault Seq**"/>
    <filter source="get-property('FAULT')" regex="TRUE" description="">
        <then>
            <log separator=", **inside Then*"/>
            <property xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" name="Code" expression="//soapenv:Fault/faultcode" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" name="Message" expression="//soapenv:Fault/faultstring" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <log separator=", **inside Else*"/>
            <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Code" expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Message" expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        </else>
    </filter>
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <FaultDetails xmlns="">
                <Date>$1</Date>
                <ServiceName>$2</ServiceName>
                <messageId>$3</messageId>
                <TransactionId>$4</TransactionId>
                <ErrorCode>$5</ErrorCode>
                <ErrorMessage>$6</ErrorMessage>
                <RequestBody>$7</RequestBody>
            </FaultDetails>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_DATE')"/>
            <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ServiceName')"/>
            <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('MessageID')"/>
            <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('TransactionId')"/>
            <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Code')"/>
            <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Message')"/>
            <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('IncomingRequest')"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <log level="full" separator=", **Before Calling QueueEndpoint**"/>
    <property name="FaultBody" expression="$body/FaultDetails" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <store messageStore="faultToQueue" description=""/>
    <log level="full" separator=", **Before Send**"/>
    <send/>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Coul'd you share the messages logged by the log level="full" in the sequence "InitializeFaultLogger" and the other just behind payloadFactory mediatior in the sequence "ProxyFaultSequence" ?

Comment: INFO - LogMediator To: /services/TestFaultSeq,** initialize fault***WSAction:
urn:mediate,**initialize fault***SOAPAction: urn:mediate,** initialize fault***MessageID: urn:uuid
:71c29050-9948-4d64-9b99-91befcb6beee,** initialize fault***Direction: request,** initialize fault*
**ServiceNAme = SN:/services/TestFaultSeq,** initialize fault***TransactionIdW = 008,** initialize
fault***CallerW = ,** initialize fault***IncomingRequestW = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.x
mlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><transactionId>008</transactionId><trump>hello</trump></soapenv:Body>

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><FaultDetails><Date>8/26/15 11:23 AM</Date><ServiceName></ServiceName><messageId>urn:uuid:dc787156-0eed-4efd-9254-b4341a3e55a6</messageId><TransactionId></TransactionId><ErrorCode>ns1:Client</ErrorCode><ErrorMessage>No such operation 'transactionId'</ErrorMessage>
<RequestBody></RequestBody></FaultDetails></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: This first one is from "InitializeFaultLogger" and the second comment is from the "ProxyFaultSequence"  in the second one if you see the ServiceName, TransactionId and RequestBody tags are empty..

Answer (score 0):

I have the same behavior, it sounds like WSO2 (ESB 4.8.1) create a new (empty) MessageContext to send the fault message to the fault sequence when you use FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT=true

If you remove the property FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT :

- the  soap fault go to the outSequence and your properties are set correctly.
- a technical error (can't connect for exemple) is sent to the fault sequence and your properties are set correctly
- in the outSequence, you can test the response message with get-property('FAULT') and decide to call your faultSequence : your properties are set correctly

You should create a Jira.

Comment: if there is a connection timeout in that case Nothing is returned to the client and wso2 esb gets the following error when sending back..
[2015-08-26 14:15:53,298] ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the /services/TestFaultSeq U
RL.

Comment: In case of a connection timeout, your fault sequence should be executed : if ERROR_CODE exists, there is no message : therefore, you have to create your own soap fault using fault mediator "makefault"

Comment: I also just observed the error `The system cannot infer the transport information from the <url_here> URL`.  Turns out I had forgotten to prefix the URL with `https://` lol.